# Installing oursql on Mac OS Lion successes but import in python fails. **Why?**

Tags: python, macos, installation, package

I followed the installation instructions for installing oursql on Mac OS X. Since

```
sudo pip install oursql
```

told me, that it couldn't find `mysql_config` I (located it with `locate mysql_config` and) told it where to find it by

```
sudo MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config pip install oursql
```

I added the terminal output at the bottom for readability reasons. After that I fired up python in terminal (On Mac OS Lion it is python 2.7 now,...) and did

```
>>> import oursql
```

but python keeps telling me:

```
>>> import oursql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oursql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oursql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What do I miss? Any suggestions?

---

### Terminal Output, of pip installation:

```
Downloading/unpacking oursql
  Downloading oursql-0.9.2.tar.bz2 (113Kb): 113Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package oursql

Installing collected packages: oursql
  Running setup.py install for oursql
    skipping 'oursqlx/oursql.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'oursql' extension
    /usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config --cflags
    llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/oursql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o -I/usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/include -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_10Connection___cinit__’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:4630: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_10_Statement_execute’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:10219: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
    oursqlx/oursql.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6oursql_16_DBAPITypeObject___richcmp__’:
    oursqlx/oursql.c:17597: warning: implicit conversion shortens 64-bit value into a 32-bit value
    llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c oursqlx/compat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/compat.o -I/usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/include -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    /usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config --libs
    llvm-gcc-4.2 -Wl,-F. -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/compat.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursql.so -L/usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread
    ld: warning: ignoring file build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/oursql.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
    ld: warning: ignoring file build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/oursqlx/compat.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
    ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Successfully installed oursql
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: This did the job: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"`

Comment: thanks for posting the solution, exactly the problem I just had. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the job:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I had this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install a full MySQL you can compile oursql with the mysql-connector-c.

Download mysql-connector-c, unzip and install:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-osx10.5-x86-64bit.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
tar -xvf mysql-connector-c-6-1.0.2-osx10.5-x86-64bit.tar
cd mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-osx10.5-x86-64bit
sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp lib/* /usr/local/lib/
sudo cp -r include/* /usr/local/include/
```

Download and unzip oursql:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k/py3k-0.9.3/+download/oursql-0.9.3.zip
unzip oursql-0.9.3.zip
```

Compile oursql:

```
cd oursql-0.9.3
sudo python setup.py build_ext
```

This has been verified to work with OSX 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.2 and Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for a solution to installing oursql on OSX 10.10.5. I had previously installed mysql using brew `brew install mysql`. For those looking to install oursql on yosemite, here is what works for me:

1) Download the package manually. See links [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oursql/0.9.3.1).

2) Open `oursql/oursql-0.9.3.1/oursqlx/_exceptions.c` in your favourite text editor

3) Comment the last “default”, should look something like this:

```
    /*default:
        if (err >= ER_ERROR_FIRST && err <= ER_ERROR_LAST)
            return _oursqlx_ProgrammingError;
        else if (err > CR_MIN_ERROR && err < CR_MAX_ERROR)
            return _oursqlx_InterfaceError;*/
```

4) Now try running setup again:

```
[sudo] python setup.py install
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way for installing mysql-server on mac os snow leopard is trying to install from source file in order to make sure you are compiling mysql for the correct architecture x86_64.