# Aptana (eclipse) does not recognize modifications to PATH written in .bashrc

Tags: python, eclipse, bash, path, aptana

I encountered and solved [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6780350/641514) earlier this day and now I run into something similar but in another context.

When I fire up python (2.7) in my mac Terminal (Mac OS Lion) and do

```
import oursql
```

everything is fine.

When I do the same within a python script in the Aptana IDE I get the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salah/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/pubmap/src/scripts/parse_all_dblp_authors.py", line 10, in <module>
    import oursql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oursql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oursql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

This is the same error as in the problem above which I used to solve by adding

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"
```

to .bashrc and

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

to .bash_profile.

Why does this have no effect on Aptana? By the way Aptana is a derivate of eclipse so everything relevant to eclipse should be relevant to Aptana, too - at least I think so...

### Edit:

A suggestion by Peter in his answer below brought me a possible solution. Just set the path right into the interpreter Options of Python in Aptana/Eclipse/Pydev. See the following Screenshot:

[image: Interpreter Settings for Aptana]

Comment: Perhaps aptana/Eclipse simply sets the python path differently?

Comment: @matt b: Is there a way to determine that?

Comment: I find the best way to debug python search path problems is to examine them at runtime.  `os.environ['PATH']` will show you the PATH environment variable python has been given.  [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) is the path python is using to search for modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Pydev, but the [Pydev docs on configuring the interpreter](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) are probably worth a look.

Python IDEs usually let you configure the environment python is run in when you run from the IDE.

Also, having .bashrc change your $PATH will only change the environment variable for bash sessions.  Unless you run Aptana from bash changing your .bashrc won't change the envirnment variables Aptana gets.  See [setting-environment-variables-in-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x).

Comment: Your first link brought me enlightenment. I just went to the Interpreter options of python and added "/usr/local/mysql/lib/" as environment variable to the **Environment** section. I posted a screenshot as Edit to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio does not read .bashrc. However it does include other files in the following order:

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ] ; then . /etc/profile; fi   

if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ] ; then . ~/.bash_profile;
elif [ -f ~/.bash_login ] ; then . ~/.bash_login;
elif [ -f ~/.profile ] ; then . ~/.profile;

[[ -f ~/.aptanarc ]] && . ~/.aptanarc
```

Cheers,
Max

Comment: I mentioned above, how I source .bashrc in bash_profile. If Aptana includes .bash_profile, wouldn't .bashrc be loaded automatically?